# Wordpress Admin javascript automatically changing URL

Tags: wordpress

I have a kinda complex proxy in front of Wordpress which works pretty ok with `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` hard set in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME',    'http://grigri/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://grigri/blog');
```

I can log on `http://grigri/blog/wp-login.php` which responds with a 302 towards `http://grigri/blog/wp-admin/` which seems fine.

The problem is, right after I load the admin interface the URL in the address bar is changed to `http://grigri/wp-admin/` and "most of" the links are also omitting the `blog` part. I say "changed to" because there is no HTTP call of any kind happening, just the URL changing.

If I disable javascript everything is fine: the URL is not changed. Does anyone know how to stop this behaviour?